# Calling Child Component Method From Parent Methods Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to call child component method from my parent component and need to send object. I have code below that gives me this error: Cannot read property 'RunMe' of undefined

what I am missing?

child component:

```
runMe = (item)  => {
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    if (item.hidden) {
        this.showErrorMsgEvent.emit();
    } else {
        this.highLightEvent.emit(item);
    }
}
```

Parent:

```
@ViewChild(childComponent, { static: true }) childComponent;

ListenIframeEvents(){
    window.addEventListener("message", this.displayMessage, false)
  }
  displayMessage (item) {
    this.childComponent.RunMe(item)
  }


<child-component #childComponent></child-component>
```

I have googled and most answers suggesting adding the # selector but that does not work for me.

FYI: if I run this.childComponent.RunMe() this function under the ngOnInit() it works. So I dont understand what Iam doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in line
`window.addEventListener("message", this.displayMessage, false)`

change it to
`window.addEventListener("message", this.displayMessage.bind(this), false)`

**UPDATE:**

When you pass a method to a function as a parameter, it will lose it's context (`this`). To enforce it's context to use our context, we use `.bind()` to make it's context (`this`) explicit.

For more info, check out https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-this/

Comment: Damn it! Thanks a lot! it works now!!!  can you explain it a bit further?

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 possible issues here.
the 1st one is: child-component lies under some stuctural directives like *ngIf. here marking child as `{static: false}` should fix the problem. 
other case is you are using "displayMessage" method too early, when the template of your parent isn't rendered yet. if so, put `this.displayMessage(...)` call inside of `ngAfterViewInit` angular lifecycle hook

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately changing from static: true did not worked. I tried ngAfterViewInit  as well. Above answer solved my issue, but I have no idea  how..